# Why git reset --hard doesn't reset commit hash in submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-reset

I have project with 4 submodules, 2 of them are out of sychronisation:

```
$ git submodule status
+ae633d13612e49a4d636ade1b20de7c306de9a40 devops-tools (heads/master)
 361fad5d187573d9bbb6aef67599f434c0bb7260 factorie (factorie_2.11-1.2-74-g361fad5d1)
 e702f2ffe7fa785acc97983500be6b6f995d5fa1 foundation (heads/master)
+69330f56f5db54c28a95752c7cc3a974af9cdd5e spookystuff (0.3.0-RC1-1167-g69330f56)
```

The little `+` indicates that these commit hashes are not staged, the synched commit hashes can be seen in the following message:

```
$ git submodule summary
* devops-tools 2e576eb...ae633d1 (2):
  > Additional tests for local and chained passports
  > Add policy for github issue 278

* spookystuff feeec3e...69330f5 (3):
  > fix an NPE caused by val overriding def ctg
  > move 1 closure out of test body to avoid a NotSerialisable error
  > fix a serialisation error merge process name & command into a single condition Fixed a few test case due to parser injection Additional tests for local and chained passports fix 2 pattern matching errors caused by type erasure several refactorings that use more accurate names
```

I want to synchronise them, so I execute the following command:

```
$ git add *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
datapassports.iml
target
Use -f if you really want to add them.
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at e1d426df8 issue 284, ...

$ git submodule update --init --remote --recursive --force
Submodule path 'devops-tools': checked out 'ae633d13612e49a4d636ade1b20de7c306de9a40'
Submodule path 'factorie': checked out '361fad5d187573d9bbb6aef67599f434c0bb7260'
Submodule path 'foundation': checked out 'e702f2ffe7fa785acc97983500be6b6f995d5fa1'
Submodule path 'spookystuff': checked out '69330f56f5db54c28a95752c7cc3a974af9cdd5e'
```

but it appears that nothing changed, the command `git reset --hard` FAILED to set submodules to the correct hash: `2e576eb` and `feeec3e` respectively. What's the purpose of this design and how to fix it?

Comment: Regardless of what your `git reset --hard` did or did not do to your superproject index and work-tree, your subsequent `git submodule update --remote --recursive --force` yanked your four submodules onto four specific commits. The `--remote` part tells Git: *ignore the recorded hashes in the superproject* so what's in your superproject index becomes irrelevant.

Comment: yeah you are right, I thought remote simply means to fetch from remote if the commit hash doesn't exist locally